# Get generic field type at runtime via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I am having trouble accessing the runtime type of `id` via reflection from `MyClass`.

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity<T> {

    @Id
    private T id; //I need to access the runtime class of T

}

public class MyClass extends AbstractEntity<Long> {}
```

I am using java reflection and have access to the `id Field` in the superclass.

I tried using:

- `field.getGenericType()`: which returns `TypeVariableImpl` with a value `T`.
- `field.getType()` which returns `Object`.

I want to access `Long` as the field type.

I am writing a library for others to use and there are a few issues:

1. I don't actually know if the type is a generic type or a regular type, I only know it is annotated with `@id`.
2. I don't know where in the class hierarchy this field is located.

Here is the method I am using to get hold of all fields in the class hierarchy.

```
private Set<Field> getAllFields(final Object object) {
    final Set<Field> fields = new HashSet<>();
    fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()));
    Class<?> superclass = object.getClass().getSuperclass();
    while (superclass != null) {
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(superclass.getDeclaredFields()));
        superclass = superclass.getSuperclass();
    }
    return fields;
}
```

I then filter this list for field annotated with `@Id` of which there should only be one.

Comment: You can't get type of `T` at runtime because of [Erasure of Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html)

Comment: OK, the trouble I am having is that I need to set the value of the field to the appropriate type that is coming in via JSON.  It can be a  Java primitive type, String, type wrappers or the BigXXX classes.  So I kind of have a set of possible types.  Any ideas of how I could detect if the type I am about to set onto the variable is possible?

Comment: Try to use Buhake Sindi suggestion with class parameter.

Comment: But that assumes I know something about the class hierarchy and how it is setup.  I know nothing other that the field is annotated with @Id.

Answer (score 2):

Generics are not *reified* at run-time. This means the information is not present at run-time.

One way is to know the class type of the generic parameterized type, i.e., `Class<T> entityClass`.

There are couple of ways to achieve this. You can either have a default constructor and reflectively get the class type:

```
this.entityClass= (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                            .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Or create a constructor, passing the the Generic class type on the constructor:

```
protected AbstractEntity(Class<T> entityClass) {
    this.entityClass = entityClass;
}
```

Then, your concrete entity class can pass its class type by default, like so:

```
public class MyClass extends AbstractEntity<Long> {

    public MyClass() {
        super(Long.class);
    }
}
```